# Php inheritance question

Tags: php, oop

How do I use a function that I defined in a parent class in the child class?

for example if i use a class like the below

```
<?php

class mat

{

function square($x)

{

return $x *$x;

}

}


class matchild extends mat

{

function doublesquare($x)
{

return square($x) * square($x)

}

}

?>
```

If I try the above , I get an error saying that the square function is not defined.

Answers and suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `this`

```
return $this->square(x) * $this->square(x);
```

Check out PHP's [basic documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) on classes and objects.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues with your snippet. But the answer you're looking for is:

```
$this->square()
```

Answer (score 0):

`parent::square(x) * parent::square(x)`

Answer (score -2):

In matchild's contructor call `parent::__construct()`

```
class matchild extends mat
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Then you can call any method contained within the parent with `$this->`

Comment: You don't need to call a super class' constructor to use its methods.